# Access RelatedManager for a model created by multi-table inheritance

Tags: django, django-models

Summary: Is it possible to access a model sub-classed via multi-table inheritance via a relatedmanager on a related model instance?

Details:

Assuming the following model definitions..

```
class City(models.Model):
    ...

class Place(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

class Restaurant(Place):
    ...
```

I'd like to be able to access all restaurants in the city of Portland like this:

```
portland = City.objects.get(id=1)
portland.restaurant_set.all()
```

However `restaurant_set` or similiar doesn't seem to be an exposed `RelatedManager` on `City`, only `place_set` is exposed.

Is there a way to expose `restaurant_set`, `restaurants`, or similar as a related manager when accessing a model instance of `City`?

I've also tried created a custom manager for Restaurant, like this:

```
class RestaurantManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

class Restaurant(Place):
    objects = RestaurantManager()
```

However it doesn't seem to get me any closer to what I want.

Apologies in advance as this is just pseudo-code, not the actual models I'm using in my project/app. It's possible I've introduced an error here not in my actual code base, and will happily clarify and update if so.

Also, if it's possible to accomplish this without the use of a 3rd party package (like django-polymorphice etc) I'd prefer that, but if the only reasonable way is to use one of these packages, I will accept that as the answer.

Finally, I'm on Django 1.8 and cannot upgrade for the time being.

Comment: Could you clarify why you want this? The equivalent queryset is `Restaurant.objects.filter(place__city=portland)`. Is it that you prefer the syntactic sugar of `portland.restaurant_set.all()`, or is there a reason you need an actual related manager attribute?

Comment: Yes, it's that I prefer the syntactic sugar, all my other code is written this way, it makes my code easier to read, etc.

I can def. do `Restaurant.objects.filter(place__city=portland)` and have been doing that for now. I get functionally there is no difference, it's purely a matter of style I guess.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get Django to do that for you. If you're fine with using a regular queryset you could manually add a `restaurant_set` property to `City` and return the relevant queryset. I don't really like that solution myself, since it makes an already leaky abstraction even leakier.

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks for your help. I agree, adding a property on City to get at the Restaurant model feels wrong to me, entangling my models together in  a way. I guess if there's not a better way, I'll just call `Restaurant.objects` instead.